# Google Maps Heatmap Android Display

Tags: java, android, google-maps, heatmap

I have multiple geo-locations that have a weight of +1 or -1 in an android app. I'd like to be able to plot these points as an overlay to a google-maps activity. I thought that the best way to view the data is not on a point-by-point basis but by shading regions depending on the average density of its values. I have done a few searches and I want a heatmap-like rendering and was wondering if anyone had any direction as to how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using a library then you can use Mapex.

https://code.google.com/p/mapex/source/browse/MapExLib/